# How do you get a grunt task to save a new simple mongodb document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, gruntjs

I've got a problem with using mongoose and custom grunt tasks together. All i want to do is make a task that behaves like a simple put request, by taking the parameters I give the task in the command line and processing/saving them to the database. However, when I expect to find it in the DB after adding it.. I can't find it anywhere.

The goal is to create a new company and save 4 simple parameters save from a "grunt addcompany:a:b:c:d" command.

Here is the "company" model (I've kept it very basic):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Company = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  info: String,
  also: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Companies', Company);
```

This is at the top of my Gruntfile.js:

```
var schemaCompany = require('./models/company'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
db = mongoose.connection,
Company = mongoose.model('Companies', schemaCompany);
```

This is the task:

```
grunt.registerTask('addcompany', 'add a company', function(n,e,i,a) {
  var done = this.async();
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/app-test');
  db.on('open', function () { 

    var co = new Company({
      name: n,
      email: e,
      info: i,
      also: a
    });

    co.save(function (err) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('success!');
    });

    console.log(co);

    db.close();
  });
});
```

When I type this in the CLI:
    grunt addcompany:name:email:description:more_stuff
The CLI returns with:

```
  Running "addcompany:name:email:description:more_stuff" (addcompany) task
  {
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email",
    "info": "description",
    "also": "more_stuff",
    "_id" : ObjectID(" ~object id here~ "),
    "__v" : 0
  }
```

Although it creates an Object ID, it never saves anywhere. Nothing is showing up in the companies collection in the app-test db. What am I missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're closing `db` before `co.save` completes (calls its callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
db.on('open', function () { 

var co = new Company({
  name: n,
  email: e,
  info: i,
  also: a
});

co.save(function (err) {
   // log the doc
   console.log(co);
   // log the error
   console.log(err);
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('success!');
  // close the database after 'co' is saved.
  db.close();
  done(true);
});
```

});